# A puzzling rebus puzzle

Tags: rebus

Solve the following rebus puzzle:

```
DROPALME
```

Comment: What's with linking to the other puzzles in the tag? Isn't that accomplished with the tag on its own, or am I missing something?

Comment: I could not post the rebus in this short form. Stackexchange software claimed that it was to similar to other rebus posts on this site. Then I added some empty sentence and I was allowed to post.

Comment: Nice and simple ;)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Is it:

> Pal - in - drome
>  Dro(pal)me

Answer (score 1):

I just solved another one just like this, it's obviously

> palindrome

because

> pal is in drome, i dont feel like i need to explain this much more, but dro"pal"me take out pal, which is in drome, palindrome!

Comment: Especially obvious given someone answered this yesterday :)

Comment: i didn't look at that though, but i guess it looks that way, oh well, i dont care about rep really.